# Labeling intertwined images with polygons

Tags: object-detection, image-segmentation, yolo, semantic-segmentation, yolov8

I am developing an instance segmentation model with the Yolov8 model. While labeling the photos, I often hesitate about how the model will be affected. Can you help me with this by looking at the examples below

Example:
[image]

For example, in this photo, the sheep are very intertwined with each other. Especially the bodies of the sheep in the back are barely visible. The model will encounter various sheep herds during the product phase. How should I label such photos?

Comment: you shouldn't worry about the labeling but the *training*, the loss function. label clear individuals clearly, label "undifferentiated sheep soup" and model the loss function such that in training the network isn't punished for arbitrary decisions of the labeler. do not be afraid of taking labeling decisions from the trained network, having humans inspect/critique/correct them, and update the training data from that... or not. the network may decide to label one instance that is really multiple, or multiple that are one, or any other invalid thing.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "model the loss function such that in training the network isn't punished for arbitrary descisions of the labeler"?

Comment: "undifferentiated sheep soup" was my attempt to explain. a human labeler can't make heads or tails of the far end of that group of sheep. any labeling decision would likely contain errors (relative to omniscient truth). both humans and machines would make errors because it's impossible to decide from just the picture. a "fair" (to the model being trained) loss function would accept the model _not_ labeling anything in that uncertain area, even if a human labeler said "it's sheep-ish there", but it would also accept the model labeling individuals there, even if the human refused to bother